# Format date more nicely php

Tags: php, date

so currently I have 3 variables holding the day as an integer, month as a 3 letter representation of the month, and the year as 4 digits.

So for example

```
$day = '16';
$month = 'nov';
$year = '2013';
```

Now if I want to display it like

```
November 16th 2013
```

I was thinking I would have to generate a unix timestamp from my data, then use

```
date('F jS Y', $timestamp);
```

I'm not sure how to properly generate the unix timestamp though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
echo date('F jS Y', strtotime("$month $day $year"));
```

The key piece is the [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) function that will parse a date string into a timestamp for you.

Working example: http://3v4l.org/INV8d

Answer (score 3):

Follow the OOP way , it's cool ;)

```
<?php 

$day = '16';
$month = 'nov';
$year = '2013';
$newDate="$day-$month-$year";
$date_new = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y',$newDate); 
echo $newformat=$date_new->format('F dS Y'); //November 16th 2013
?>
```